# How to avoid payments getting updated for multiple Customer invoices in Odoo 8?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

Here are the steps to reproduce:

I created a customer invoice say `EX001` and name of the customer is `Ted` and trying to register payment against this invoice as amount of `Rs 10000/-`.

But when I try to register payment against this invoice, the payment entry is not updated against this invoice, instead the amount has been split up against invoices `EX002` - `EX010` (all the invoices are of parent company of Ted).

Most of the times registering payment against one invoice works fine. Sometimes do not.

I would like to know whether it has anything to do with bug fixes. This is an older version of `odoo-8`.

Comment: When I try to pay one invoice, it fully reconciles all other invoices of the same parent Customer. Anyone with any guidance? Really appreciate it.

Comment: Ok I found out, its auto re-conciling invoices of a partner. Is there any way I can stop it?